Spark MongoDB SamplePartitioner
I am connecting to MongoDB Atlas using mongodb-spark-connector v10.3
I am using a SamplePartitioner with a pipeline that matches on a certain date range and projects only the _id column:
[{'$match': {'dateReceived':{'$gte': '2024-07-12T05:00:00.000000Z','$lte': '2024-07-12T09:15:00.000000Z'}}},{$project:{_id:1}}]

Since I am using the SamplePartitioner, the mongodb-spark-connector automatically appends the _id column to the $match stage and the resultant pipeline becomes:
[
         {
            "$match":{
               "$and":[
                  {
                     "_id":{
"$gte":"ca8866b865271263919bb74cb355cdf5955de54d80123368c9409ad12d622bcd",
"$lt":"d039be1aaf69134b5b24009ca41d5763090bb8b77bd923b5ae3b38c6624d28c9"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "dateReceived":{
                        "$gte":"2024-07-12T05:00:00.000000Z",
                        "$lte":"2024-07-12T09:15:00.000000Z"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "$project":{
               "_id":true
            }
         }

The issue with this as I see, is the _id boundaries are created based on the samples it collects from each partition but it does not employ a min and a max range to get all the possible records.
Is my understanding correct?
Has anyone encountered this issue where the data returned from Mongo is not complete.

That match provide the minimum, but no maximum, were there other queries submitted besides that one?

it contains the $lt if you scroll to the very right ; due to bad formatting it just is not visible; let me fix that; @Joe

ok, so that query is providing a min(inclusive) and a max(exclusive) range for _id, which should be getting all the results for that partition.  Is it now querying multiple partitions?

the challenge I am facing is on how it is generating the min and max value of the _id ; there are records in Mongo for the dateRange provided above, but their _id value is greater than the max value calculated by the mongo-spark-connector.
(I am not providing the _id clause in match, its being calculated and inserted automatically by the mongo-spark-connector and that min/max range is inaccurate)
@Joe

you are using the sample partitioner, so it should submit a separate query for each partition

With SamplePartitioner I see different results (count) with every run, but overall it is fast.
When I replace the Partitioner with PaginateIntoPartitionsPartitioner, the counts are consistent (and accurate) every single time but it is much slower.
Any idea why? I looked at the code and nothing suggested to me why PaginateIntoPartitions would be significantly slower.
This link suggests that the fix is done, but apparently not
@Joe

Ah, so the question you really wanted to ask is: Why does SamplePartitioner not return complete results?, the answer to that is because the sample partitioner takes a sample of the documents in each partition instead of reading all of them.  You can set a samples per partition option to control how many documents from each partition.
